# failed with error 10068: "invalid operator: $oid"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, sidekiq

just updated to the latest version of mongoid (3.1.0) and sidekiq (2.7.2)
now i'm getting the error : `failed with error 10068: "invalid operator: $oid"`
from looking into the code i see a select like that: `@selector={"_id"=>{"$oid"=>"[some id]"}}` 
what can get wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

adding this to my `gemfile` fixed the issue:

```
gem 'multi_json', '1.5.1'
```

i guess something is wrong with the latest version (1.6.0)

**EDIT:** the gem has been updated to new version (1.6.1) that fixed this issue. more here:
https://github.com/intridea/multi_json/issues/89

Comment: This did not work for me (see my answer for a more complete description of the problem).

Comment: This is no longer accurate, because Sidekiq dropped MultiJson usage on `#perform_async`. Sidekiq now uses the core JSON module. See [this comment by Sidekiq's author](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/951#issuecomment-19497803)

Comment: You may also need to set cookies_serializer with :hybrid value instead of :json. More detail: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/15111#issuecomment-43134650

Answer (score 6):

This is actually happening because BSON::ObjectId is not part of JSON... so when Sidekiq tries to serialize the args to the worker, it pukes. Check out this comment: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/951#issuecomment-19497803

The fix is simply to convert IDs to strings when performing a job like:

```
EmailSubscribe.perform_async(user.id.to_s)
```